# AVFoundation - Depth data capturing after raw freezes the camera preview (captureSessionIsMissing)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, depth

I am working on camera application for iOS using AVFoundation framework. It has 2 options for capturing, either in RAW (DNG) or depth mode. It works fine except the scenario when I first make raw image and then the depth one. After that preview layout freezes (picture is being saved to the gallery anyway though) and when I play around with the toggle which is responsible for switching to depth mode XCode's console shows that captureSessionIsMissing is thrown. It only happens when a picture is taken in this sequence, so just switching between modes doesn't give such effect.

What I've figured out as well is that if cameraController.switchCameraDevice(to: .rearDual) inside toggleDepthCapture() function is changed to .rearWide it works fine, but I need to work with a dual camera in this case.

**EDIT:** code stops executing after `if let depthData = photo.depthData` (depthData is nil) in

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                     didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto,
                     error: Error?)
```

Testing on iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X

XCode Version 10.0 beta 6

Deployment target 11.4

ViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func toggleRawCapture(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        //raw capture is only allowed in rear camera mode
        if let position = cameraController.currentCameraPosition,
            position == .rear,
            sender.isOn, cameraController.rawCaptureMode == false {
            //if depth mode is on, first disable it
            if toggleDepthCaptureSwitch.isOn {
                toggleDepthCaptureSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
            }
            do {
                try cameraController.switchCameraDevice(to: .rearWide)
            }catch(let error) {print(error)}
            cameraController.rawCaptureMode = true
            cameraController.depthMode = false
        }else {
            toggleRawCaptureSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
            cameraController.rawCaptureMode = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func toggleDepthCapture(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn, cameraController.depthMode == false {
            //if raw mode is on, first disable it
            if toggleRawCaptureSwitch.isOn {
                toggleRawCaptureSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
            }
            //check the position of the camera (rear or front)
            if let position = cameraController.currentCameraPosition {
                if position == .rear {
                    do {
                        // Allow rear depth capturing on iPhone 7 Plus, 8 Plus and X models only
                        switch UIDevice().modelName {
                            //
                        case "iPhone 7 Plus", "iPhone 8 Plus", "iPhone X": try cameraController.switchCameraDevice(to: .rearDual)
                        default:
                            //try cameraController.switchCameraDevice(to: .rearWide)
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Operation not available (only on iPhone 7 Plus, 8 Plus and X)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it", style: .default, handler: nil))
                            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    } catch(let error) {print("Rear error: \(error)")}
                } else{
                    do {
                        // Allow front depth capturing on iPhone X only
                        if case UIDevice().modelName = "iPhone X"
                        {
                           try cameraController.switchCameraDevice(to: .frontTrueDepth)
                        } else {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Operation not available (only on iPhone X)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it", style: .default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)}

                    }catch(let error) {print("Front error: \(error)")}
                }
            }
            cameraController.depthMode = true
            cameraController.rawCaptureMode = false
        }else {
            //check the position of camera (rear or front)
            if let position = cameraController.currentCameraPosition {
                if position == .rear {
                    do {
                        try cameraController.switchCameraDevice(to: .rearWide)
                    }catch(let error) {print(error)}
                } else{
                    do {
                        try cameraController.switchCameraDevice(to: .frontWide)
                    }catch(let error) {print(error)}
                }
            }
            cameraController.depthMode = false
        }
    }
```

CameraController.swift

```
func switchCameraDevice(to cameraDevice: CameraDevice) throws {
        guard let currentCameraDevice = currentCameraDevice, let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {
            throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing
        }

        captureSession.beginConfiguration()

        func switchToRearDualCamera() throws {
            guard let rearCameraInput = self.rearCameraInput, captureSession.inputs.contains(rearCameraInput),
            let rearDualCamera = self.rearDualCamera else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation}

            self.rearCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearDualCamera)
            captureSession.removeInput(rearCameraInput)

            if captureSession.canAddInput(self.rearCameraInput!) {
                captureSession.addInput(self.rearCameraInput!)
                self.currentCameraDevice = .rearDual
                self.photoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
            }else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation}
        }

        func switchToRearWideCamera() throws {
            guard let rearCameraInput = self.rearCameraInput, captureSession.inputs.contains(rearCameraInput),
                let rearWideCamera = self.rearCamera else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation}

            self.rearCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearWideCamera)
            captureSession.removeInput(rearCameraInput)

            if captureSession.canAddInput(self.rearCameraInput!) {
                captureSession.addInput(self.rearCameraInput!)
                self.currentCameraDevice = .rearWide
                self.photoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = false
            }else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation}
        }

        func switchToFrontTrueDepthCamera() throws {
            guard let frontCameraInput = self.frontCameraInput, captureSession.inputs.contains(frontCameraInput),
                let trueDepthCamera = self.frontTrueDepthCamera else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation}

            self.frontCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: trueDepthCamera)
            captureSession.removeInput(frontCameraInput)

            if captureSession.canAddInput(self.frontCameraInput!) {
                captureSession.addInput(self.frontCameraInput!)
                self.currentCameraDevice = .frontTrueDepth
                self.photoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
            }else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation}
        }

        func switchToFrontWideCamera() throws {
            guard let frontCameraInput = self.frontCameraInput, captureSession.inputs.contains(frontCameraInput),
                let frontWideCamera = self.frontCamera else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation}

            self.frontCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontWideCamera)
            captureSession.removeInput(frontCameraInput)

            if captureSession.canAddInput(self.frontCameraInput!) {
                captureSession.addInput(self.frontCameraInput!)
                self.currentCameraDevice = .frontWide
                self.photoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = false
            } else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation}
        }

        //todo: complete implementation
        func switchToRearTelephotoCamera() throws {

        }

        switch cameraDevice {
        case .rearWide:
            try switchToRearWideCamera()
        case .rearDual:
            try switchToRearDualCamera()
        case .frontWide:
            try switchToFrontWideCamera()
        case .frontTrueDepth:
            try switchToFrontTrueDepthCamera()
        case .rearTelephoto:
            try switchToRearTelephotoCamera()
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    }



    func captureImage(completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let captureSession = captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {
            completion(nil, CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing);
            return
        }

        var photoSettings: AVCapturePhotoSettings
        if let availableRawFormat = self.photoOutput?.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first, self.rawCaptureMode{
            photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(rawPixelFormatType: availableRawFormat,
                                                   processedFormat: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
            // RAW capture is incompatible with digital image stabilization.
            photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = false
        }
//        else if self.photoOutput?.availablePhotoCodecTypes.contains(AVVideoCodecType.hevc) != nil {
//             photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc])
//        }
        else{
             photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
        }

        photoSettings.flashMode = self.flashMode
        if let depthEnabled =  self.photoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliverySupported, self.depthMode {
            photoSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = depthEnabled
            photoSettings.embedsDepthDataInPhoto = true
            photoSettings.isDepthDataFiltered = true
        }

        self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
        self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock = completion
    }
}

 func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                     didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto,
                     error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock?(nil, error)
        }else if photo.isRawPhoto{
            // Save the RAW (DNG) file data to a URL.
            rawImageFileURL = self.makeUniqueTempFileURL(extension: "dng")
            do {
                try photo.fileDataRepresentation()!.write(to: rawImageFileURL!)
            } catch {
                fatalError("couldn't write DNG file to URL")
            }
        }else if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation(){
            self.compressedFileData = imageData
            if self.depthMode{
                if let depthData = photo.depthData{
                    saveDepthData(depth: depthData)
                    // Create a depthmap image
                    let context = CIContext()
                    let depthDataMap = depthData.converting(toDepthDataType: kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32).depthDataMap
                    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: depthDataMap)
                    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)!

                    let imageOrientation: UIImageOrientation
                    switch currentOrientation {
                        case .portrait:             imageOrientation = .right
                        case .portraitUpsideDown:   imageOrientation = .left
                        case .landscapeLeft:        imageOrientation = .down
                        default:                    imageOrientation = .up
                    }

                    let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: imageOrientation)
                    self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock?(uiImage, nil)
                }
            }
        }else{
            self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock?(nil, CameraControllerError.unknown)
        }
    }

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                     didFinishCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
                     error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error capturing photo: \(error)");
        }
        guard let compressedData = self.compressedFileData else {return}
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            // Add the compressed (JPEG/HEIF) data as the main resource for the Photos asset.
            let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
            creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: compressedData, options: nil)
            if self.rawCaptureMode{
                // Add the RAW (DNG) file as an altenate resource.
                let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
                options.shouldMoveFile = true
                creationRequest.addResource(with: .alternatePhoto, fileURL: self.rawImageFileURL!, options: options)
            }
        }, completionHandler:{(_, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error occurred while saving photo to photo library: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }



enum CameraControllerError: Swift.Error {
        case captureSessionAlreadyRunning
        case captureSessionIsMissing
        case inputsAreInvalid
        case invalidOperation
        case noCamerasAvailable
        case unknown
    }
```